# How do I return a json object of my database table

Tags: mysql, json, python

I'm creating a web client that uses data from my database to plot markers on a google map. So my collumns are id, name, address, lat, lon, description. My client gets the data from a route in my restful server.

I am currently using flask in my python server.  This is the current code on my route on my server.

```
@testRestServer.route("/dbMap", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getData():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM markers ")
    return jsonify(cursor.fetchall())
```

This is the output of the json i get, however i'm unable to manipulate it correclty to work with my google maps code as it has none of the headers as reference.

```
[
  [
    1, 
    "Test1", 
    "york", 
    53.95734, 
    -1.086833, 
    "test1"
  ], 
  [
    2, 
    "Test2", 
    "york", 
    53.961533, 
    -1.085244, 
    "test2"
  ], 
  [
    3, 
    "Test3", 
    "york", 
    53.963051, 
    -1.078202, 
    "test3"
  ], 
  [
    4, 
    "Test4", 
    "york", 
    53.963104, 
    -1.082185, 
    "test4"
  ]
   ]
```

I'm not sure why its not outputting like this and not with the column names like this which i believe is what i need to be doing.

```
[
{"name": "test1"
 "address": "york"
  "lat" : "53.963104"}
]
```

I still need to work out if its best to return the column header as a string or key but if i can try either option and see which works best.
Any assistance on how I could return an output like the latter would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

This is the latest code with the error TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

```
@testRestServer.route("/dbMap", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getData():
    #    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM locations ")
    #    return jsonify(cursor.fetchall())

    records = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM locations ")
    payload = []
    content = {}
    for result in range(records):
        content = {'id': result[0], 'name': result[1], 'address': result[2], 'lat': result[3], 'lon': result[4], 'description': result[5]}
        payload.append(content)
        return jsonify(payload)
```

Comment: Welcome to [dba.se]! This looks more like a programming question and less like a DBA question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that purpose, you have to build your own json array from the resultset

The last with lon is only a guess but you get the drift.

```
@testRestServer.route("/dbMap", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getData():
    records = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM markers ")
    payload = []
    content = {}
    for result in records :
        content = {'name': result[4], 'address': result[1], 'lat': result[2], 'lon': result[3]}
        payload.append(content)
        content = {} 
    return jsonify(payload)
```

Comment: Thank you for that, it seems to be what i'm looking for.  When i try and impliment the code, records and content comes up with value not used and rv is underlined in red as an unresolved reference.  Could you advise on this please

Comment: good please [accept it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: It also is telling me the for statement is not iterable, which i'm unsure to as why

Comment: i know it is because rv is not defined but records is, use the updated code

Comment: thank you, i've just worked that out.  I'm getting a few errors with this such as TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' on the content = {'name etc line.

Comment: how does markers  look like, check how many colimns it has actualy

Comment: so it has 6 in total, id, name, address, lat, lon and description but i've added those in.

Comment: and you started at 0 til 5?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: could please add you new source code, the error meaase is strange

Comment: I have added it to the bottom of my question

Comment: Could it be anything to do with the 'id', 'name' etc not being integers or should that not matter?

Comment: you missed a line before the return and the return in not correct indented  you are new to this

Comment: I'm not that experienced with python, your're right on that.  However ive corrected it so its indented like yours and the line i missed out.  However i still get that error and local variable content is not used now apparently.

Answer (score 1):

So with a bit of hunting and adapting, i resolved the issue with a different method.  I'll post it here incase someone else has an issue similar to this in the future.

The completed route in the server to get the json working correctly is

@testRestServer.route("/dbMap", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getData():

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM locations ''')
row_headers = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]  # this will extract row headers
rv = cursor.fetchall()
json_data = []
for result in rv:
    json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers, result)))
return json.dumps(json_data)
```